# How to feed TF-IDF vectorizer output as input to a neural network for classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, tf-idf

I am a beginner and I am trying to do sentiment classification on IMDB dataset by first using a TF-IDF vectorizer and then using the TF-IDF vector to train a neural network for binary classification. As pre-processing, I have removed stopwords.

I have tried the following method but every time end up with a new error. Kindly please help on the best way to code the problem statement: **I want to use TF-IDF vectorization along with Neural Networks for Binary sentiment Classification of imdb reviews.**

I have written the following function to create the TF-IDF vectorizerr:

```
def Ngram_Vectorizer(reviews_train, reviews_test):
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range=(2,2))
    tfidf.fit(reviews_train)
    feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
    reviews_train = tfidf.transform(reviews_train)
    reviews_test = tfidf.transform(reviews_test)
    return reviews_train, reviews_test
```

After getting the TF-IDF vectors, I am passing it to a shallow neural network as follows:

```
    def NeuralNetwork(reviews_train, labels_train, reviews_test, labels_test):
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = reviews_train.shape, activation = 'relu'),
          tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(reviews_train, labels_train, validation_data = (reviews_test, labels_test), batch_size = 128, epochs = 5)
        model.summary()
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 136, in main
    NeuralNetwork(reviews_train, labels_train, reviews_test, labels_test)
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 72, in NeuralNetwork
    model.fit(reviews_train, labels_train, validation_data = (reviews_test, labels_test), batch_size = 128, epochs = 5)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1063, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1117, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 573, in __init__
    dataset = dataset_ops.DatasetV2.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 682, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 3003, in __init__
    self._tensors = structure.to_batched_tensor_list(batched_spec, element)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py", line 352, in to_batched_tensor_list
    component), element_spec, element)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py", line 326, in _to_tensor_list_helper
    reduce_fn, zip(nest.flatten(element_spec), nest.flatten(element)), [])
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py", line 323, in reduce_fn
    return encode_fn(state, spec, component)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py", line 352, in <lambda>
    component), element_spec, element)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\sparse_tensor.py", line 346, in _to_batched_tensor_list
    out_type=dtypes.variant)]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_sparse_ops.py", line 498, in serialize_many_sparse
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[1] = [0,3105402] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.
    Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy.

 [Op:SerializeManySparse]
```

Then to solve the above error I used ****tf.sparse.reorder(reviews_train), tf.sparse.reorder(labels_train)**** as follows to modify my input to neural network:

```
def NeuralNetwork(reviews_train, labels_train, reviews_test, labels_test):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = reviews_train.shape, activation = 'relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(tf.sparse.reorder(reviews_train), tf.sparse.reorder(labels_train), validation_data = (tf.sparse.reorder(reviews_test), tf.sparse.reorder(labels_test)), batch_size = 128, epochs = 5)
    model.summary()
```

But I got a new error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 136, in main
    NeuralNetwork(reviews_train, labels_train, reviews_test, labels_test)
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 72, in NeuralNetwork
    model.fit(tf.sparse.reorder(reviews_train), tf.sparse.reorder(labels_train), validation_data = (tf.sparse.reorder(reviews_test), tf.sparse.reorder(labels_test)), batch_size = 128, epochs = 5)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 823, in sparse_reorder
    sp_input = _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_input)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 71, in _convert_to_sparse_tensor
    raise TypeError("Input must be a SparseTensor.")
TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.
```

Thirdly I tried using **todense() on the TF-IDF output** as follows:

```
def Ngram_Vectorizer(reviews_train, reviews_test):
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', ngram_range=(2,2))
    tfidf.fit(reviews_train)
    #print(tfidf.vocabulary_)
    feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
    #print(feature_names)
    #pickle.dump(tfidf, open('tfidf_vectorizer.pkl', 'wb'))
    reviews_train = tfidf.transform(reviews_train).todense()
    reviews_test = tfidf.transform(reviews_test).todense()
    return reviews_train, reviews_test
```

But again this threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 141, in <module>
    main()
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 129, in main
    reviews_train, reviews_test= Ngram_Vectorizer(reviews_train, reviews_test)
  File "neuralnetwork_tfidf_classifier.py", line 50, in Ngram_Vectorizer
    reviews_train = tfidf.transform(reviews_train).todense()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 847, in todense
    return asmatrix(self.toarray(order=order, out=out))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 1025, in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1185, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.14 TiB for an array with shape (50010, 3140004) and data type float64
```

**Any help or guidance towards the right direction will be very helpful. Thank you everyone in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

The last error means that the training would run, but the memory of your PC is not sufficient (happens often even to the biggest computers). Try running it with only a small part of the dataset to see whether it works.

Comment: Yes, It works for small dataset with a size of 2000 reviews not more. For the full dataset I couldn't run it on Google Colab too. Is there any other work-around to train this same architecture on bigger data?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue? I am running into similar problems here...

Comment: How was it resolved at last?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to float instead of sparse. See below:

```
reviews_train = tfidf.transform(reviews_train).astype('float16')

reviews_test = tfidf.transform(reviews_test).astype('float16')
```